# How to make the else statement work when performed on a dataframe

Tags: r

I don't know how to make the else statement work.
When `myLifeTab$lx` is below 97721 I want `myLifeTab$px27` to be equal to zero.
The while loop works but the else statement does not.
I have tried to do this with the if and for function, but the else statement still doesn't work.
Could anyone tell me how to fix this problem?
Thank you.

```
while (myLifeTab$lx <= 97721) {
  myLifeTab$px27 <- myLifeTab$lx/97721
} else {
  myLifeTab$px27 <- 0/myLifeTab$px27
}
```

Comment: `else` is for `if-else` statements. A `while` loop is for looping while a condition is met. If you want to loop, then create a [loop](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tutorial-on-loops-in-r) and use an [if-else](https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/if-else-statement/) statement to change what you do..

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

> I don't know how to make the else statement work.

`else` is used in if...else statement and performed this way:

```
if (test_expression) {
  statement1
} else {
  statement2
}
```

In your case, you would be tempted to write something like this (Wrong!):

```
# doesn't work
if (myLifeTab$lx <= 97721) {
  myLifeTab$px27 <- myLifeTab$lx/97721
} else {
  myLifeTab$px27 <- 0/myLifeTab$px27
}
```

The reason it doesn't work is because `myLifeTab$lx` refers to a column of a dataframe, then this is actually a list. In fact you'll get a warning message that says:

> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

So the `if` comparison is **only made** against the first element of `myLifeTab$lx`, which is clearly not what you want. If the first element is a number below 97721, then all the values in that column will be executed as if they all passed the `if` conditional check.

### Solution

Back to your desired output:

> When `myLifeTab$lx` is below 97721 I want `myLifeTab$px27` to be equal to zero.

You can first create your function this way:

```
# if value passed into argument is below 97221 (evaluate to true)
# set value to 0; else, value is divided by 97721
 myfunc <- function(x){
    ifelse(x <= 97721, 0, x/97721)
}
```

Now you have a function that you can pass into this column in your dataframe. You do it this way:

```
myLifeTab$px27 <- lapply(myLifeTab$lx, myfunc)
```

The `lapply()` function apply that function onto each element of the `lx` column (list) and return a list, you then assign this list onto `px27` column, yielding either a 0 or a scaled-down number (division) depending if they are above or below the 97721 threshold set forth in `myfunc`.

As a quick aside, I'm unsure why you would have a formula like this  `0/myLifeTab$px27`. You could have simplify it to just `0` since 0 divided by anything would still be 0.